# MS Graph API Get Devices and Users of partner tenants in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, graph, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to access our partners users and devices through a PowerShell script without logging into every tenant separatly.

I've created an app registration in our Azure AD and granted some permission I found online.
But using the ParnterCenter Module doesn't work and using the Graph Module I do not find proper API calls to access our partners data.

Does someone know a proper way to do that?

[image]

```
Import-Module MSAL.PS
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph

$ClientId = "###"
$TenantId = "###"
$ClientSecret = "###" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

$Token = Get-MsalToken -ClientId $ClientId `
                       -ClientSecret $ClientSecret `
                       -TenantId $TenantId
Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken $Token.AccessToken
```

Comment: Are you getting any specific error?

Comment: The way you're trying this isn't going to work as far as I know (long story why, but it comes down to: how do you specify which tenant to use when requesting the token?).

Comment: The permission required for getting the list of devices please check this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/device-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=powershell#permissions

Comment: @bluuf I don't specify a tenant, as I don't have enough permission (or so it seems) to request tenant IDs

Comment: @Mason ok, but if there is no way to specify a tenant, how do you expect the Graph API to know for which tenant you'd like to request data for? This is why its not possible at the moment, at least not in the way you are trying this (the solution I'm using at my employer actually involves creating an app reg in the customer tenant, combined with a certificate we store in a keyvault)

Comment: @bluuf thats why I asked for the proper way to do it

Comment: @Mason and like I'm saying: you can't do this the way you are trying. You'd either have to create an app reg in each tenant OR create one multi-tenant app reg (where you'd still have to authorize this app from each tenant)